# Where is the controller placed using $routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

With `ng-controller="myController"` you know exactly what DOM element is associated with the controller, because it's put directly into your HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
```

with `$routeProvider`, I don't know what DOM element is associated with the controller.  Is the controller injected into the uppermost element on the DOM?  According to the documentation, the controller is a JavaScript constructor function, and the controller is associated with the newly created scope.  But I don't know where that newly created scope is?

Is the controller simply part of $routeProvider, and $routeProvider is an object?

Comment: Controller isn't part of `$routeProvider`. `$routeProvider` is provider (api) and part of `ngModule` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngView [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)

if you put

```
<div ng-view=""> your route will change html here </div>
```